# clojure unit-testing with-redefs

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I have something like this:

```
(ns server.core
  (:require [db.api :as d]))

(defrecord Server [host port instance]
  (start [c]
    (let [connection (d/connect (:host c) (:port c))]
      (assoc c :instance connection)))
  (stop [c]
    ;; close the connection
    ))

(defn new-server
  [host port]
  (map->Server {:host host
                :port port}))
```

And the unit-tests code

```
(ns server.core_test
  (:require [server.core :refer :all]
            [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(deftest server-test
  (testing "Calling start should populate :instance"
    (with-redefs [d/connect (fn [h p] [h p])]
      (let [server (start (new-server "foobar" 12313123))]
        (is (-> server :instance nil? not))))))
```

Running the code above with `boot watch test` throws an error similar to:

`Unable to resolve var: d/connect in this context`

And then I modify the test code so it requires the `db.api`

```
(ns server.core_test
  (:require [server.core :refer :all]
            [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [db.api :as d]))
```

I ran the tests again, this time `d/connect` still refers to `db.api`.

Any advice?

Comment: How do you know it that it still refers to db.api? Have you tried putting a `println` statement into your redefined `d/connect` function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to require `db.api` in your test code so the var `d/connect` is accessible:

```
(ns server.core_test
  (:require [server.core :refer :all]
            [db.api :as d]
            [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(deftest server-test
  (testing "Calling start should populate :instance"
    (with-redefs [d/connect (fn [h p] [h p])]
      (let [server (start (new-server "foobar" 12313123))]
        (is (-> server :instance nil? not))))))
```